# Как динамически менять изображение в python Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pillow

Мне надо, чтобы по нажатии определенной кнопки менялось отображаемое на canvas изображение

```
pilImage = Image.open(imagepath)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = pilImage)
ball = game.create_image(250,250, image = image)
```

без создания другого pilImage. Например, при нажатии w определенная картинка меняется на другую. '.config' не работает.

Необходимо, что бы изображение на холсте менялось визуально

Comment: Как именно вы хотите менять изображение? Читать из файла новое или видоизменять старое?

Comment: я сам точно не понимаю, мне нужно лишь чтобы визуально одно изображение подменялось другим без смен переменных, чтобы имитировать хождение, например. Если менять переменные то невозможно использовать move(). Жаль, что простой config не работает